# Account/ Opportunity sharing

Tags: visualforce, opportunity, sharing

Is there a way to add "Account Access" option under the "Opportunity Access" option (like it is shown in Account sharing) without creating a custom VF page and just by playing around with the sharing settings on the individual Opportunity sharing page? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No. [OpportunityShare](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunityshare.htm), the underlying Share table, does not have an option to include access to the Account. Please note, however, that because of [Implicit Sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_object_relationships_implicit_sharing.htm), the account is automatically shared with Read access (but not Edit) when the Opportunity is shared. You cannot change this default behavior.